# PHP Time Management for a simple Token System

Tags: php, database, authentication, token

I have to create a Token System for logging users up. Here's how it works...

---

**1. Login Process**

1. PHP checks if the provided information is valid. If is valid it moves further.
2. It creates a token in database with user's id. The token required some values but the mainly I'm right now focused on implementing are create_time, expire_time.

How to create lets say two variables **$create_time** and **$expire_time** where **$create_time** is the value right at now at the script execution and **$expire_time** is lets say 3 hours later the **$create_time**.

---

**2. Token Usage**

Also when I have fetched the results from database, how will I be able to check the time difference if token is expired or valid.

---

Reason of Implementing Tokens-
I have been trying to create an API for an Application. Rather than passing Username, and Password through every Request, I thought it will be much easier for client's usage as well as safety to provide tokens rather than full info with every request.

Thanks for reading and again thanks for answering.

Comment: What Database are you using

Comment: You should store the token in a way in which distinguishing between the create time and expire time is easy. So to check if a token is valid, you get the value from the database, strip all unnecessary parts then compare the current time with the expiry time.

Comment: There's already a lot of stuff out there made just for what you want to do/use. Post the code that you had difficulties with; we'll be happy to help you then.

Comment: Sorry, It was just a general question. I had to implement the code yet. I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your variables using DateTime:

```
$create_time = new DateTime;
$expire_time = new DateTime;
$expire_time->modify('+3 hours');
```

For checking just use something like this:

```
$time_now = new DateTime;
if($expire_time_from_db < $time_now){
 //its expired
}}
```

Comment: Not for me, for the OP